# How do you create a search bar that will let you search for all the different fields in your database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example, On my Home/Index page I display the information in my database. I want to create a search bar that will let me search for all the values that match my search.

e.g. database has employee, salary, and ID. I select employee search button and search for "Bob". The search will show me all the employees named Bob.

I have it right now so that I can display everything on the database to my index.cshtml from my HomeController. I can do simple searches like

```
public ActionResult Index(string employeeName){
//If employeeName, I return employeeName
//else I return something else}
```

But I am not sure how to search for multiple fields and return them. I know I can't use overloaded ActionResults, so I tried using [ActionName] and create different Index methods with differing parameters, but the search wouldn't work. I'm also not using ADO.NET entity model because I'm trying to do this in an existing code that doesn't implement entity model.

edit- Home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller{

    public ActionResult NameSearch(string EmployeeName)
    { //code to display JUST employee's name that matches the Employee variable} 
    public ActionResult SalarySearch(double salary)
    { //code to display JUST employee's sthat matches the salary variable} 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      //return View(model); the model has all the data that will be displayed in index.cshtml
    }
```

index.cshtml-

```
<h2>Employee</h2>

<form action="/" method="get">
<input type="text" name="EmployeeName" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<h3>Search Salary</h3>

<form action="/" method="get">
     <input type="text" name="salary" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

So there are multiple search boxes. If I search "bob" in the Employee search I want to return all the matching names. But I am not sure If I am going at this right,

final edit-

I got this done by using something like this in Index.cshtml

```
<p>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("serialDisplay", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <p>
        serial Number: @Html.TextBox("serialNumber") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    }
</p>
```

Comment: so you have one text field to put the search keywords in, but then couple of different buttons (or radios) that would trigger a different type of search depending on the button chosen?

Comment: I have x search bars for x fields I want to search for. In the Index.cshtml, I have <form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="employee" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>.      And then I would have a method in the HomeController that accepts "employee" string?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to offer a good suggestion.  Can your `Index` method just have two parms, say `searchField` and `searchValue` and then each column's search box uses a different value for `searchField`?  Or use a `ViewModel` and pass more strongly typed data in.

Comment: If I am reading this right you want a single search box that returns results from searches in multiple fields.  So if you entered "1234" you would get people who's salary is $1,234 and also people who's ID contained "1234" correct?

Comment: @stephen.vakil I have edited my post to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do. I basically want to do [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/perform-paging-searching-sorting-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/), but with search box for each element in the database. So ultimately I want to have a dropdown box where I can choose what element I want to search for and then search for it in a single search box. But I want to take it one step at a time.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? or Whatever ORM you are using?!

Comment: @JonGlazer I updated my original post for clarification. I want a search bar for each element in the database, employee name, salary, and etc. Then If I search for something in that particular search box, I want to return all the matching elements and display it. So ultimately I want to have a dropdown box where I can choose what element I want to search for and then search for it in a single search box. But I want to take it one step at a time.

Comment: I would really recommend something like ElasticSearch for this as what you are proposing could be a major drain on your db.

Comment: @Valkyriee I am not using entitiy framework. I am using asp.net restful service web app? Sorry, I am new. I am not sure if that answers your questions.

Comment: @nurdyguy ok, I will look into it. I'm new :)

Comment: To keep it simple it might be an option to create a full-text index on all columns and create a stored function on the server that accepts `@clue varchar(100)` and does `contains(*, @clue)`.

Comment: @user4660931 so there is no database, Either your RESTful Web Service Provides a Method To do this (Filtering), or you can call everything and Filter them using JQuery, Knowing that you are using RESTful AngularJS does this very well as well.

Comment: @user4660931 there is an alternative way as well, you can call the method to get a list, and save it into your database, then whenever you want it back load it from database (Filter within your Query) but i suppose this is not you are looking for.

Comment: @user4660931 Since you are new, using the db as you were asking is ok.  I just wouldn't do it in a production environment.  ElasticSearch is AWESOME but it is not easy...  It isn't super hard either but probably not the best idea for a new programmer.  Something good to keep in mind for the future though.

Comment: Check this excellent article by Tom Dykstra on Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application, and especially the part which shows how to Add a Search Box to the Students Index Page https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand the question now. You're really concerned more with the parameters on the Controller method signature, not how to do the internal logic in the controller, correct?

Are you aware that parameters can be defaulted to null or some other sensible value if they're not passed in?

```
public ActionResult Index( int? id = null, string employeeName = null,double? salary = null){
// if id != null, add it to the where clause.
// if employeeName != null or white space, add it to the where clause (most browsers will send it as "" if the user doesn't enter anything). 
// if salary != null, add it to the where clause, you probably actually want a salaryMin and salaryMax
```

}

This is the simplest way to approach optional parameters, there's also more you can do with custom model binders. You could also play around with Routes to send you to differently named methods based on parameters supplied. It also lets you construct things so that you can do salary AND name.

edit: link to MS documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx#Optional Arguments